# Exception While sending response from Controller to JSP page

Tags: json, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I am trying to send a response from spring mvc controller to jsp page and I got an exception

Firstly, I tried to return a list to jsp page

code for list:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody 
public List<Users> getUsers(@RequestParam(value = "intermediate" ,required = false) String intermediate)throws java.text.ParseException{
    List<Users> list = null;

    int intermediateSelection = Integer.parseInt(intermediate);

    list = getUsersBySelection(IntermediateSelection) //This will return list of users  

    return list;
    }
```

Then I tried to return a JSONObject to the JSP Page

Code for JSONObject :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody 
public JSONObject getUsers(@RequestParam(value = "intermediate" ,required = false) String intermediate) throws java.text.ParseException{
    List<Users> list = null;

    int IntermediateSelection = Integer.parseInt(intermediate);

    list = getUsersBySelection(IntermediateSelection);  //This will return list of users

    Iterator<Users> iterator=list.iterator();

    JSONObject UsersJSON = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray usersArray = new JSONArray();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Users users = iterator.next();

      JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
      object.put("Id", users.getUserId());
      object.put("Name", users.getUserName());
      object.put("Group", users.getGroup());

      usersArray.add(object);
    }

    UsersJSON.put("users", usersArray);

    //System.out.println(UsersJSON.toString());

    return UsersJSON;
    }
```

Either of them didn't work for me. I got an exception like this.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:682)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
```

Users Pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int userId;
    private Role role;
    private Groups groupId;
    private UserType userType;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private Boolean isActive;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(int userId, Role role, Groups groupId ,UserType userType, String userName, String password, boolean isActive) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.role = role;
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.userType = userType;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "UserID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RoleID", nullable = false)
    public Role getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GroupId", nullable = false)
    public Groups getGroup() {
        return this.groupId;
    }

    public void setGroup(Groups group) {
        this.groupId = group;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserTypeID", nullable = false)
    public UserType getUserType() {
        return this.userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(UserType userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    @Column(name = "UserName", nullable = false)
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Column(name = "Password", nullable = false)
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "IsActive", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIT")
    public Boolean isIsActive() {
        return this.isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(Boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `Users.java` class? do you have any relationship in that class?

Comment: See the edited code..

Answer (score 5):

From [this blog post](http://keenformatics.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-solve-json-infinite-recursion.html),

> For Jackson to work well, one of the two sides of the relationship
>   should not be serialized, in order to avoid the annoying infinite
>   recursive loop that causes our StackOverflow error.
>
> So, Jackson takes the forward part of the reference, for example an
>   attribute of a java class (i.e. `List<Role>` roles in User class), and
>   converts it in a json-like storage format; this is the so-called
>   marshalling process.  Then, Jackson looks for the back part of the
>   reference (i.e. `List<User>` users in `Role` class) and leaves it as it
>   is, not serializing it. This part of the relationship will be
>   re-constructed during the deserialization (unmarshalling) of the
>   forward reference.

**Solution:**

1. Add the `@JsonManagedReference` In the forward part of the relationship (i.e. `Users.java` class):
2. Add the `@JsonBackReference` In the back part of the relationship (i.e. `Role.java` and `Groups.java` class):

`Users.java`(example code):

```
@Entity
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "UserID", unique = true, nullable = false)

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "RoleID", nullable = false)
@JsonManagedReference
public Role getRole() {
    return this.role;
}

...
```

`Role.java(example code)`:

```
@Entity
public class Role implements java.io.Serializable {

 @Id 
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private int id;

 @OneToMany
 @JsonBackReference
 private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

...
```

and the same way goes for

`Groups.java`

```
@Entity
public class Groups implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="groups")
@JsonBackReference
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

...
```

> Another useful annotation you could check is `@JsonIdentityInfo`: using
>   it, everytime Jackson serializes your object, it will add an `ID` (or
>   another attribute of your choose) to it, so that it won't entirely
>   "scan" it again everytime. This can be useful when you've got a chain
>   loop between more interrelated objects (for example: `Order ->
>   OrderLine -> User -> Order` and over again).
>
> In this case you've got to be careful, since you could need to read
>   your object's attributes more than once (for example in a products
>   list with more products that share the same seller), and this
>   annotation prevents you to do so. I suggest to always take a look at
>   firebug logs to check the JSON response and see what's going on in
>   your code.

Hope this helps.